# Page formatting

Tags: javascript, html

Please be advised that I DON'T know HTML and I am attempting to learn this. So that being said, I have a page that I'm making for my girlfriend for Christmas. I would like to make the text that I have on the right side of the page bigger and also only extend a 300px amount so that the pictures that change be to the left of it and you don't have to scroll down to see the all of the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<title>Heather I Love You!</title>
</head>
<body style= background-color:#A8A8A8>


<!========This is the header===========>
<div id="header" style= "background-color:#00FF33;" >
<h1><p id="hheader"></p></h1></div>

<!=============The side bar that will allow a list of where she Wants to go==========>
<div align="right"><i><p id="phrases" style="text-height="50" width:300px></p></i></div>
<div id="Menu" Style="background-color:#3A75D4;height:300px;width:125px;float:left;">
<div align="center"><img id="cur_pic" height="400" src="pictures/cake.jpg" /></div>


<button type="button" onclick="ChangeHead()">Next Picture</button><br>



<!--Functions-->
<Script>
function ChangeHead(){
  var g = document.getElementById("hheader");
  var x = "Heather this is a series of Pictures, Videos, and Poems to show you the love that I have for you!";
  var boys = "Here are some pictures of us and the boys";
  var cake = document.getElementById("cur_pic");
  var fam = "I Love spending the time that we get together, even when I have a Broken foot";
  var poems = document.getElementById("phrases");
  var cakepoem = "Here are some of my favorite times that I have with you. Doing the date Night is a great time that I really enjoy with you. I cant wait until we can spend a week together in North Carolina, yes we'll be with your mother, but the best part about it will be that we will be together!";
  var boyspoem = "Jenner and Watson are a big Part of our life, Jenner says momma I love you and can I have some food?";
  var  fampoem = "Honey, when I see this picture of you and the kids, well, it shows me all the love that you have for me and the family.";             
  if (g.innerText == fam)    {
    g.innerHTML = x;    
    cake.src = "pictures/cake.jpg"; poems.innerHTML = cakepoem ;
    } else if (g.innerText == x)    {
    g.innerHTML = boys; 
    cake.src = "pictures/jenner wanting to pee.jpg";    poems.innerHTML = boyspoem;}
 else {
    g.innerHTML = fam;
    cake.src = "The Family and Friends/H_Jules_bre_at_zoo.jpg";poems.innerHTML = fampoem;
    }
};
ChangeHead();
</Script>

</body>

</Html>
'
```

Comment: Use CSS. I would stay away from the HTML `style` attribute, which is what JavaScript sets. If you're doing that dynamically setting `style` with JavaScript is fine. Also, it's a good practice to keep all of your HTML lowercase, with the exception of attribute values, which are Strings in quotes, and DOCTYPE declarations. It should not take too long to learn HTML and CSS. I like books. Good Luck.

Comment: ok I will use CSS, PLease advise where I should go to figure this out.

Comment: Although many People on this site will say stay away from w3schools, I find the information easy to understand, and usually accurate. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp . The first 5 or so chapters should give you a good start. Of course, you should learn HTML first. There's a link on that same page. I would learn XHTML, so you can transfer your code to any site.

Comment: Since I had not much to do tonight, I made you this: http://jsfiddle.net/hJvC7/ hope it will help. To finish it, give an eye to w3schools or http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxAyb/

Css can be included in your code by adding a `style` tag in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* css goes here */
</style>
```

It's terrible code, but it'll wrestle the elements into position for you.

To learn html, go here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/
Css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

w3c schools isn't the best resource, but it's got most of the basics there, and is easy to understand for beginners.

Also, for javascript, you'll want to mostly load content dynamically only when you need to. For the most part, you can just stick the content into the html, then change it when you need to. Javascript works great for that. If you want a simpler interface to learn, though, check out [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

I wish you luck! I did pretty much this exact thing two years ago. Picture viewer using my rudimentary understanding of html for my girlfriend, at Christmas. Now I'm a professional php developer!

Comment: that is awesome! I am very new to it, but I've spent several hours on the internet researching this I was able to get the site up and going thanks for the hints on the pages, I do more reading and then I update it. thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. And a tip about Stack Overflow - if this answer was helpful, go ahead and upvote. And if it solved your problem, mark it as accepted.